# Export the graph generated by rCharts in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny, nvd3.js, rcharts, ggvis

I want to be able to export the charts generated in my shiny application using rCharts to Image and PDF formats. Is there any provision in the `rCharts` library for that?

I have earlier used `ggvis`, It gives an option for resizing the chart in the browser and also an option to download the chart in HTML or PNG format. Anything similar to that?

**Edit 1:**

I'm using `nvd3` and `polyCharts` as my charting libraries currently.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

To download as image or `pdf` you can use `a$exporting(enabled = T)`, assuming your chart is called `a`.

```
library(rCharts)
a <- hPlot(Pulse ~ Height, data = MASS::survey, type = "scatter", group = "Exer")
a$exporting(enabled = T)
a
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! does it work for `NVD3` and `polyCharts` too? Or it's only for `highCharts` ?

Comment: I tried this for `NVD3` and `polyCharts` but it is not working. :( It says: ‘exporting’ is not a valid field or method name for reference class “Polycharts"! and same for NVD3... Do you know any workaround for this?

Comment: I believe this is only a highcharts feature. Alternatively, you could issue a call to the `htmlwidgets::saveWidget()` function

Comment: @PaulGovan Where to put that call? inside renderChart2 ?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment above, I was a bit too quick to respond, as the `htmlwidget::saveWidget()` function is meant for widgets developed under the [htmlwidgets.org](http://htmlwidgets.org) framework. However, rCharts has a similar function:

```
library(rCharts)

a <- nPlot(Pulse ~ Height, data = MASS::survey, type = "scatterChart", group = "Exer")
a$save("demo.html", standalone=TRUE)
```

Where 'demo.html' is standalone html file. Creating a png is as simple as taking a screenshot. Note that you can also call this function in a shiny app.

Comment: Hi Paul! I'm aware about the save function. I didn't understand the "taking screenshot" part of your answer. How does taking screenshot solve the problem? And what about pdf?